# Singularitygs layout in layout padding

Tags: layout, sass, singularitygs

I am using a main layout of two grid-spans, that serve as a content and the right panel. Then, in content, I have three grid-spans, that are equal columns. Like this:
1. Parent span: 6 and 6
2. Child span of first column: 4 and 4 and 4

What happens, is that when I use grid-span for the content 3 columns,  then they have paddings, all three of them, and the padding of the last column visually adds to the padding of the parent container to create a double gutter.

However, when I use float-span, then we the last of the three content columns does not have a padding, and looks visually longer than the first two columns.

Is there a way to make all 3 child columns same size, AND have the third column without padding, without having to hack into singularitygs with css overrides?

[image]

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on http://sassmeister.com , update your post with a link to it, then reply in comments.

Comment: In my sassmeister, it works as expected http://sassmeister.com/gist/7be2b0a8791bf105af54. On my dev site, the grid-span adds paddings for gutters, rather than using margins. See the screenshot attached. As the result, the last column (child 3) ends up having no padding (because it is last)? and ends up being larger than the previous two.

Comment: You've got some styles or Configuration that produces that unwanted padding. Double-check your styles. Also share the output of `@debug $singularity`.

Comment: Ok managed to reproduce. The difference if because tha gutter is fixed in pixels. Please look at the sandbox. If you look at the Child 3 green paragraph in dev tools, you will see, that it's actually wider than the other two, because it's parent column has no gutter padding being last. http://sassmeister.com/gist/7be2b0a8791bf105af54 - I have highlighted columns so you can see how first two have horizontal padding and the last one not. I guess there is no way around that. Must be the penalty for using fixed gutter...

Comment: I don't see a problem. That's how fixed gutters work in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how Singularity's fixed gutters work in the first place.

To apply backgrounds to columns without including their padding, use subcontainers.

See this demo: http://sassmeister.com/gist/b2d957171427022de7c7

**PS** Don't nest your Sass code. Use semantic classes to address elements directly. Use two-level depth to position children within parents, e. g.:

```
.parent
  .child-1
    +grid-span(1,1)
  .child-1
    +grid-span(1,2)
```

Never use three-level depth, unless you've got a really-really good reason.